# How to make Product - Variation relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, relationship, lumen

I am using Laravel and creating a e-commerce website. I want to make relationship between product and variation, i have already created tables to handle product and variation:

**database design:**

[image: click to see database design]

I am using **hasManyDeep** relation and using the following Laravel package:

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```
public function productSkuValue() {
    return $this->hasManyDeep(
        ProductSku::class,
        [
            ProductVariant::class,
            ProductVariantOption::class,
            ProductSkuValue::class
        ]
    );
}
```

also included the following package in my Product model.

```
use Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasManyDeep;
```

I am getting following error:

[image: click to see error]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you give us the name of model where is this relation is included? It can be confusing otherwise, even with your DB design.

Comment: I have created the model in Product model, and using it with productController, is this you are asking?

Comment: Yes, because I had no idea which was the source model. To be clear you are trying to define : Produts => ProductVariant => ProductVariantOption => ProductSkuValue => ProductSku, is it correct?

Comment: yes, please help

Comment: @MathieuBour please help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can refer to this, this may help you.

table 1: Attributes => (id int(11) primary key AI, name varchar(255), createdAt timestamp, updatedAt timestamp);

table 2: products => (id int(11) primary key AI, name varchar(255),slug varchar(255), createdAt timestamp, updatedAt timestamp);

table 3: sku => (id int(11) primary key AI, code varchar(255),price int,createdAt timestamp, updatedAt timestamp, product_id int FK);

table 4: attribute_options => (id int(11) primary key AI, value varchar(255),createdAt timestamp, updatedAt timestamp, attribute_id int FK);

table 5: attribute_option_sku => (sku_id int(11) FK,attribute_option_id int FK);

Comment: You must make use of these relationships:

// app/Models/Product.php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function variations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Variation::class);
    }
} 

// app/Models/Variation.php
class Variation extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}